# How do you write `FORCE INDEX (index_key)` on MySQL using Knex.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I have a Mysql query like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name FORCE INDEX (index_key)
```

How do I write `FORCE INDEX (index_key)` with knex.js?

Comment: Look at `knex.raw()`

Answer (score 3):

I did

```
edwDiamondClient()
  .select('column_name')
  .from(knex.raw('table_name FORCE INDEX(index_key)'))
```

Comment: To have consistent quoting for identifier name you could use `??` mapping for them. In this case that you are not using case sensitive `table_name` it doesn't matter though. `knex.raw('?? FORCE INDEX(??)', ['table_name', 'index_key'])`.